# What is Twilio trying to tell me?! (Error 12200) (PHP)

Tags: php, twilio

I have no idea what's going on, and I can't seem to find any help documentation. Been pulling my hair for two hours now with what is probably a basic fix. It says 'check the line and column reported' but I see no line/column reported anywhere?

Here is exactly what Twilio shows me:

[Twilio Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ga1Qn.png)

Here is "my" PHP code. (Copy and pasted from quickstart)

```html
<?php
    header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Sms>Hello, Mobile Monkey</Sms>
</Response>
```

Is my free webhost causing this with a traffic analytics?

Comment: Dangit... This is the second host I've tried. Thanks, I'll try with a paid one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paul pointed out above, it would appear that your host is adding the script tag which is throwing the [12200 Error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/12200) in response to the unknown or unexpected nested elements as referenced in the documentation.